# ControlTemplates in WPF

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

Create a WPF application by defining a new Control Template for the TextBox control. You provide a custom appearance for the TextBox and implement the functionality to change that appearance when the TextBox gets focus, loses focus and when the content changes in the text element (i.e. TextChanged event occurs).

Hint: The Initial state should be a default state (with your choice of style), you can then toggle between GotFocus and LostFocus events.

This is the markup I have so far.... along with the code-behind for the textchanged requirement. Iam unable to make the background change to blue when I change the text of the textblock.  Any suggestions?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>



    <ControlTemplate x:Key="myTextBoxTemplate">

    <Border

  x:Name="templateBorder"

  Padding="50" Background="Pink"

  BorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="5"

  BorderThickness="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">



  <TextBlock>

            <!--ScrollViewer all the text box to allow entering of text-->

            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost">

            </ScrollViewer>

  </TextBlock>           

</Border>



        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">

                <Setter TargetName="templateBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>

                <Setter TargetName="templateBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>

            </Trigger>



            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                <Setter TargetName="templateBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="8"/>

            </Trigger>



            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">

                <Setter TargetName="templateBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>

            </Trigger>





        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    </ControlTemplate>



</Window.Resources>



 <StackPanel>



    <TextBox Text="Click Me" FontWeight="Bold" Template="{StaticResource myTextBoxTemplate}"

            Name="myTextBox" TextChanged="myTextBox_TextChanged" Opacity="1"/>

 </StackPanel>



 </Window>
```

method:

```
private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)

    {

        myTextBox.Background = Brushes.Blue;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ControlTemplate` you are not actually using the Property Background from the `TextBox`. Thus when you set it from the code-behind it has no effect since it's not getting used by your `ControlTemplate` Border.

Thus get your `Border` to use `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`.

Something like:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="myTextBoxTemplate"
                    TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Border x:Name="templateBorder"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="5"
            CornerRadius="5"
            Padding="50">
      <TextBlock>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                      Margin="0" />
      </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="templateBorder"
                Property="Background"
                Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter TargetName="templateBorder"
                Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="templateBorder"
                Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="8" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused"
                Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="templateBorder"
                Property="Background"
                Value="Red" />
      </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Name="myTextBox"
            FontWeight="Bold"
            Opacity="1"
            Template="{StaticResource myTextBoxTemplate}"
            Text="Click Me"
            TextChanged="myTextBox_TextChanged" />
  <Button Content="Dummy Button" />
</StackPanel>
```